# Ajaxcomplete running on any button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a slider which is loaded regular `$(document).ready(function () {}` but on some Pages I have to reload the script with `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {}` too.. Means both has to be called.

The Problem is that ajaxComplete is loading anytime I press any Button with Javascript Action.

I am calling the Javascript twice with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:5,
        lazyLoad:true,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        responsiveClass:true,
        dots: false,
}
```

and with

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:5,
        lazyLoad:true,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        responsiveClass:true,
        dots: false,
}
```

on the same Content because I have to load the ajaxComplete if I change a value.

Can I call ajaxComplete if a Class exist or what is a better way?

There is a `<select>` with dynamic values on special pages, **after user change the value** of select than I have to rebuild it.

Comment: when exactly do you have to rebuild the carousel after the ajax call? Whenever the user clicks anywhere or is there a link to click on or something similar?

Comment: There is a <select> with dynamic values on special pages, if user change the value of select than I have rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments above.
Then just rebuild the carousel when the user changes the select:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:5,
        lazyLoad:true,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        responsiveClass:true,
        dots: false,
    });
});
```

Comment: Well by this way the carousel will be loaded after <select> value has changed but I still have to wait for Ajax of the Page until it has finished loading the Page. Adding it into `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { $('select').on('change', function() {` did not solve too

Comment: Here is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610321/execute-document-ready-after-ajax-post