# Manually triggering document onready

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible to manually refire a function that has been assigned to document's onready event?

I know this is an awkward question, and it's kinda difficult to explain the situation here, but please suppose we have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

Is there a way to manually trigger this event somehow somewhere in the page? like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).trigger('ready');
</script>
```

But this doesn't work unfortunately. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you able to alter the script file holding the $(document).ready() statement ?

Comment: also this appears to be a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562229/how-to-trigger-ready-in-jquery

Comment: the jQuery `.ready()` function only allows itself to be called once.  You will have to do something like Scott suggests (put your code into a function) if you want to call the code again.

Answer (score 5):

why ? cant you simply

```
function readyFunc() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
}

$(document).ready(readyFunc);
```

then you can just call the function as needed directly

Comment: the hastiness with which you have punctuated this answer is only matched by its clarity through brevity. +1 good sir.

Comment: No, unfortunately I have no access to the actual source. I'm doing some XHR stuff and the loaded content needs to be initialized by that js function. I need to somehow fire that event to make this work.